# Can i do spark-submit application jar directly from maven/jfrog artifactory

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying/experimenting with doing spark-submit application-jar where the application-jar is actually hosted in a remote repo (not local or HDFS or S3)
Below is my example trying to run SparkPi directly from Maven:

```
spark-submit \
    --class org.apache.examples.SparkPi \
    --repositories https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central,https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases \
    --packages org.apache.spark:spark-examples_2.10:0.9.0-incubating \
    --jars https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-examples_2.10/0.9.0-incubating/spark-examples_2.10-0.9.0-incubating.jar \
    spark-examples_2.10-0.9.0-incubating.jar \
    10000
```

It doesn't seem to work nor fail, here is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      default     |  123  |   0   |   0   |   21  ||  102  |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-a0c4af8a-2537-45f2-a26d-d9d697abfb2b


confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 102 already retrieved (0kB/50ms)
20/07/17 09:53:35 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ****.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using **** instead (on interface en0)
20/07/17 09:53:35 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/07/17 09:53:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I maybe wrong in my assumption that it should work, but appreciate any feedback

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Not yet, Currently wget is used first

Comment: were you able? i have similar requirement

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! You do not need any of the `--jars`, `--repositories` or `--packages` config flags for it either. Simply supplying the full `https` URI for the application jar is enough. In your case, it would be something like:

```
./spark-submit \
    --class org.apache.examples.SparkPi \
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-examples_2.10/0.9.0-incubating/spark-examples_2.10-0.9.0-incubating.jar \
    10000
```

There is one problem in here though: in the jar you are referencing, `org.apache.examples.SparkPi` does not exist. However, `org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi` does exist!

Here you can find an example that works completely on my laptop right now (using Spark 3.3.1 locally):

```
./spark-submit \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-examples_2.10/1.1.1/spark-examples_2.10-1.1.1.jar \
    10000
```

I changed the `spark-examples_2.10` version, but the idea is the same: just supplying the URI for the application jar should be enough.

Comment: Is there a way to pass artifactory credentials in URL?

Comment: Not sure about this because I've never added credentials in the URL but you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115470/specify-user-name-and-passoword-in-jfrog-artifactory-url-in-order-to-avoid-the-p)? Let me know if it works, then I'll add it to this answer!

Comment: thank you! URLs like https://user:pass@host/path somehow do not work with jfrog.

Comment: Ohh ok so that link I sent you wasn't helpful?

Comment: anyway, thank you for the link, the artifactory instance is somehow giving not authorizing against link with creds in URL, while header does work out.